# Compiling error/query

Tags: c, syntax-error

I keep getting these errors in my code and I'm not sure what they mean, can anybody please explain to me what they mean?

Errors :

> lab62.c: In function ‘circumfrence’:
>
> lab62.c:7:1: error: expected ‘=’,
> ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘void’
>
> lab62.c:31:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token
> lab62.c:40:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’
> before ‘{’ token
>
> lab62.c:49:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or
> ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’ token
>
> lab62.c:55:1: error: expected ‘{’ at
> end of input

EDIT: I have just added semicolons to the function now I'm getting all these errors

> lab62.c: In function ‘circumfrence’:
>
> lab62.c:36:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat]
>
> lab62.c: In function ‘area’:
>
> lab62.c:44:8: error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have ‘float’ and ‘int’)
>
> lab62.c:45:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat]
>
> lab62.c: In function ‘volume’:
>
> lab62.c:50:8: error: ‘v’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
>
> lab62.c:48:19: note: previous definition of ‘v’ was here
>
> lab62.c:52:31: error: ‘r’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> lab62.c:52:31: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>
> lab62.c:54:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat]

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.147

void circumfrence(float r)
void area(float r)
void volume(float r)

int main()
{
    void (*f[3])(float) = { circumfrence, area, volume };
    int choice;
    float r;
    printf("enter a value for the radius\n");
    scanf("%f", &r);
     printf("enter a number between 0 and 2, 3 to end: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    while(choice >= 0 && choice < 3) {
        (*f[choice])(r);
        printf("enter a number between 0 and 2, 3 to end: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("program execution completed\n ");
    return 0;
}

void circumfrence(float r)
{
    float c;
    printf("you wish to process the area");
    printf("the radius is %f: ", r);
    c = (2*r)*pi;
    printf("%f", &c);
}

void area(float r)
{
    float a;
    printf("you wish to process the volume");
    printf("the radius is %f: ", r);
    a = (r^2)*pi;
    printf("%f", &a);
}

void volume(float v)
{
    float v;
    printf("you wish to process the circumfrence");
    printf("the radius is %f: ", r);
    v = (4/3)*(r^3)*(pi);
    printf("%f", &v);
}
```

Comment: Do you seriously not have semi-colons after your function declarations? And, um, 3.147 is a really bad value for `pi`.

Comment: look at the **first** error, find the line, and try to figure out why the compiler is telling you that. If you're still confused try google, and if that doesn't work post here.

Comment: check the edit im getting mor erros now aha :\ yeah i thought so, how else could i declare pi? could i include math.h ?

Comment: "how else could i declare pi": At least give it a correct value. It's not like you need to compute it yourself.

Comment: You're probably going to be surprised about your areas of a circle and your volumes, too ;)  (Hint: in C, exponentiation is a math function, not the "^" operator).

Comment: Sorry, this question is just crap. You need to learn C. There's your answer.

Comment: ahk, i'm fixing all that now ahah, it keeps saying r is undeclared and that "lf" expects a double argument.. but %lf is the syntax for double, and to travis webb yes i know i am absolutely hopeless at programming

Comment: shep, how is that the problem?

Comment: The problem is that your value for pi is wrong. pi = 3.14159265 and not 3.147. Shep was showing you how you can calculate pi with more precision.

Comment: ohk thankyou. i appreciate the help guys, sorry i am a noob ^.^. i have managed to fix up most my mistakes, but now all i have is errors for each function saying "%lf expects argument of type double but is getting type "double *" does is have to do with the fact that i am using pointers?

Comment: sorry, that's not the only problem. _Please_ look at your *first* error, type it into google, fix it, recompile, repeat. When you get sick of that find an online tutorial on C. And then if you have problems ask someone (i.e. SO)

Comment: what other errors do i have? the compiler is only telling of the ones i stated above in my last comment

Comment: @user1347895 look at the edit for my answer, it will fix these errors: "%f expects argument of type double but is getting type double *"

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add some semicolons `;` in your code after the three function declarations in the beginning. The correct code is this:

```
void circumfrence(float r);
void area(float r);
void volume(float r);
```

EDIT:
In line 44, you can't use `^` in C for what you want. You can use `a = (r*r)*pi;` or `a = pow(r,2)*pi;` Also, the same thing in line 53.

In line 50, you redeclared the `v` variable. There is a confusion between the `f` parameter and the `f` variable. You need to use another name for `v` in line 50.

EDIT 2:

When you want to print values, you don't need to use the reference. When you use `printf`, don't put a `&` in front of the variables. Do it like this:

```
printf("%f\n", c);
printf("%f", a);
printf("%f", v);
```

Comment: man, theirs always that small thing, i know that i don't need to put them their but i was just silly and didn't realize, it's working fine now, thanks alot man and to everyone else!